# How to use this design in my app?

Tags: android, android-layout, flowlayout

How to implement the design given in the link below.

[image]

I've tried different flow layout libraries but they lack customization.Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple image button can make it done.

Comment: I would suggest using a `GridView` inside a `ScrollView`

Comment: Looks like a FlowLayout, to me.

Comment: suggest me a good flow layout library with most customization available.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this type of design like this: 
**create layout like below**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_calender"
            android:text="button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_calender"
            android:text="button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_calender"
            android:text="button 1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**now create this drawable custom_button in res/drawable directory**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
</item>
```